# Returning a list of objects using a list of Ids with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have an object which is a composition between two objects, A and B:

```
class A
{
  public Id {get; set;}
  ...
  public B[] B_objs {get;set;}
}

class B
{
  public Id {get; set;}
  ...

}
```

I want to use EntityFramework and LINQ to find a list of object B when I know the object A id

dbContext

```
...
A A_object = UnitOfWork.A.FindById(id);

B[] B_Objects= A_object.B_objs ;     

IQueryable<B> query = from B b in dbContext.B
                            from A in dbContext.A
                            where( b => A.B_objs.Contains(pr.Id))
                            select b;
```

I am getting an error saying that "the number of parameters of the lambda expression does not match to the number of parameter of the delegate." How can I correct this query? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IQueryable<Patient> query = 
    from b in dbContext.B
    from a in dbContext.A
    where a.B_objs.Contains(pr.Id)
    select b;
```